# Hibernate, Persistance and delation of associations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

I have some problem with delation of associations, this is my code :

> Classe ModuleVersion

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="listModuleVersions")
private List<SuiteVersion> suiteVersions = new ArrayList<SuiteVersion>();
```

> Classe SuiteVersion

```
@ManyToMany()
private List<ModuleVersion> listModuleVersions = new ArrayList<ModuleVersion>();*
```

I would like to be able to delete automatically a suiteVersion or a moduleVersion with deletion of association. For example, if i delete a SuiteVersion with this code is delete automatically the association SuiteVersion to ModuleVersion. But if i delete a moduleVersion it doesn't automatically delete the association of SuiteVersion -> ModuleVersion. It is possible to do this automatically with ModuleVersion ?

**Update**

> This is the action perform by hibernate if i delete a module with the adding of CASCADETYPE.REMOVE ...

```
Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION_MODULE_VERSION where suiteVersions_ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION_MODULE_VERSION where suiteVersions_ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION_MODULE_VERSION where suiteVersions_ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION_MODULE_VERSION where suiteVersions_ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION_MODULE_VERSION where suiteVersions_ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
//Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION where ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
//Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION where ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from MODULE_VERSION where ID_MODULE_VERSION=?
//Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION where ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
//Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION where ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from MODULE_VERSION where ID_MODULE_VERSION=?
//Hibernate: delete from SUITE_VERSION where ID_SUITE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from MODULE_VERSION where ID_MODULE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from MODULE where ID_MODULE=?
```

I just want the part none comitted to be executed.
Thank you in advance for your help,

**Update2**

I tried to delete the module with this method implementation :

```
    public static void removeModule(Module module) {
    for(ModuleVersion moduleVersion : module.getListModuleVersion()){
        for(SuiteVersion suiteVersion : moduleVersion.getSuiteVersions()){
            sessionFactory = HibernateFactory.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            suiteVersion.removeFromModuleVersions(moduleVersion);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
    sessionFactory = HibernateFactory.getSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(module);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

But i have this problem now :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Best regards,

Florent.

P.S: I'm french, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thank you for you answer. But if i had this. the suiteVersion is also deleted. I just want the row in the table of associations suiteVersion -> moduleVersion be deleted.

I think I got it now: you want to *break* an association and to get the corresponding record removed from the join table. That's not what I understood from the original question. Anyway...

To do so, well, you have to do what I wrote, to break the association, i.e. to remove the corresponding entities from their respective association collection (you have to update both sides of the link too since it's a bidirectional association).  Something like this:

```
session.getTransaction().begin();
SuiteVersion suite = ... // retrieved in some way
ModuleVersion module = ... // retrieved in some way
suite.getModuleVersions().remove(module);
module.getSuiteVersions().remove(suite);
session.getTransaction().commit(); // the "association" record should get removed
```

But I suggest using helper methods:

```
@Entity
public class SuiteVersion {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<ModuleVersion> moduleVersions = new ArrayList<ModuleVersion>();

    ...

    public void removeFromModuleVersions(ModuleVersion module) {
        this.moduleVersions.remove(module);
        module.getSuiteVersions().remove(this);
    }

    public void addToModuleVersions(ModuleVersion module) {
        this.moduleVersions.add(module);
        module.getSuiteVersions().add(this);
    }

}
```

And then your code becomes:

```
session.getTransaction().begin();
SuiteVersion suite = ... // retrieved in some way
ModuleVersion module = ... // retrieved in some way
suite.removeFromModuleVersions(module);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

#### See also

- [1.2.6. Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir)

---

**Update:** Your "new" problem is a pure Java related problem: you can't modify a collection while iterating on it, at least not with your current approach. You need to use an [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [`Iterator#remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).

#### Related questions

- [Java: Efficient Equivalent to Removing while Iterating a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection)
- [Java: How to remove elements from a list while iterating over/adding to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626671/java-how-to-remove-elements-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-adding-to-it)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But if i had this. the suiteVersion is also deleted. I just want the row in the table of associations suiteVersion -> moduleVersion be deleted.

Comment: @Delildor: I think I misunderstood your initial question, see my update.

Comment: i try to test your method for deleting the module but i'm facing to another problem. (see update2). Thank you.

Comment: @Delildor I covered this new problem in my answer but please avoid missing problems in one question next time (your new problem should have been posted as a new question, this is an unrelated issue). One question = one problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It resolve my problem. Next Time, i will post a new question like you notice.